# Mongorestore on MAC OS failed - Failed: error scanning filesystem: invalid database name '$RECYCLE.BIN'

Tags: mongodb, mongorestore

I'm trying to import a dump into my database and I get the following error:

```
nskiqq:Downloads user$ mongorestore /Users/user/Downloads --gzip
2017-06-06T10:23:20.754+0200    preparing collections to restore from
2017-06-06T10:23:20.754+0200    Failed: error scanning filesystem: invalid database name '$RECYCLE.BIN': illegal character '.' found in db name '$RECYCLE.BIN'
```

Under the path `/USers/user/Downloads` the following files are available:

```
nskiqq:Downloads user$ ls -a
$RECYCLE.BIN        .DS_Store                           .texpadtmp
.                   .com.apple.timemachine.supported    desktop.ini
..                  .localized                          dump.zip
```

Comment: Does not appear to be any backup in there at all. But `dump.zip` looks interesting. Perhaps you should unzip it. I'm guessing the backup directories are actually inside there. For the record "gzip" != "zip". Two different things.

Comment: @NeilLunn Extracting the .zip archive solved the problem.